# Looking for a way to have a button add a collection of views to a VStack

Tags: swift, swiftui

I’m attempting to create a fitness tracking app (for practice) using SwiftUI and one of the features I require is to be able to add workouts to a page that is designated as so. I’m new to Swift and a bit confused on what logic to use. Is there say a BIF that would add a certain view to a certain place on a button push? Or is there another way to have views added to the frame by a certain trigger? More specifically I would need an HStack of 3 text fields to be dynamically added and have the info stored upon user input. It would also have to have the capacity to add multiple of these prompts.

Haven’t tried much as I’m quite lost, think I can figure out the rest if I can just find a mechanic that will spawn a view on click.

Comment: I recommend you to read about [the basics of SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui). You don't add views, either you show them/not show them, or you navigate to them. There's a lot to unwrap in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you need a variable that determines whether you show the textfields or not. That variable toggles (to 'true' or 'false') when a user pushes the button.

Like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TextFields : View {
    
    @State private var showTextFields = false
    
    @State private var textField1Input: String = "input1"
    @State private var textField2Input: String = "input2"
    @State private var textField3Input: String = "input3"

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Button("Show/Hide Textfields") {
                showTextFields.toggle()
            }
            if showTextFields {
                VStack {
                    TextField("", text: $textField1Input)
                    TextField("", text: $textField2Input)
                    TextField("", text: $textField3Input)
                }.padding()
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}

struct TextFields_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TextFields()
    }
}
```